# How to save uploaded file in Vue.js project without sending them to server?

Tags: vue.js, core-ui

I am using Vue.js for my front end and Django for the backend and Postgres Database. I have all files to display in the project are in the front-end project, not on the server-side and only the URL is saved in Database.

Now, I want to save uploaded files in the front-end using Vue.js without sending them to the Django project.

I have searched for this, but I can only find the option to send files using formData and Axios to the server-side and save them over there. But for me my frond end and backend are different project and I have to save file in front end project.

Please give any suggestions how can I achieve that?

I am using CoreUI library and CInputFile for fileupload.

```
<CInputFile
  label="Client Logo"
  name="client_logo_url"
  @change="filesChange"
  accept="image/*"
  class="input-file"
  />
```

and my script for filesChange() is:

```
filesChange(event) {

      this.system_client_logo_url =
        event.target.files[0].name;

      var fileData = event.target.files[0];
    
      const path = "/assets/images/";

     // how to write code to save file in the given path
     //something like fileData.save()

    },
```

Thank you in advance.